# Carefully select and retrieve one from a large set of data

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I don't know what to do when I want to retrieve one item in each column from data like the following.

```
|name|power|
test1|15
test1|120 
test1|40 
test2|50 
test2|80   
test2|100 
test3|1   
test3|4 
test3|10
```

The results I want.

```
|name|power|
test1|120
test2|100
test3|10
```

What I tried.

```
pickup_one = (
    beaconPickUp_three
    .withColumn('r_max_date', f.max('power').over(w.partitionBy()))
    .filter(f.col('r_max_date') == f.col('power'))
)
```

or

```
PickUp_one = beaconPickUp_three.groupBy(f.col("name")).agg({"power": "max"})
```

I need your help.

Comment: The `groupBy` code should work. What output did you get from that?

Comment: It was not the result I was looking for.
Is there anything else I can do?
`
|name|min(power)|
+-----------+---------+
|   test3|      40|
|   test2|      50|
|    test|      40|
`